# shapes recognition for shapes formed by dotted points

Tags: computer-vision, opencv

In the image, below right corner there is circle shape and triangle shape made with set of co-ordninates.I have searched extensively in the net for algorithm or approach to classify shape correctly .And yet came up with nothing.I need approach or directions to solve this problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use MINST dataset trained model, make predictions.**

[Look here.](https://www.kaggle.com/ngbolin/mnist-dataset-digit-recognizer) find the one with biggest accuracy, and the circle should be class that 
represents class of number 0.

EDIT: check this notebook where you can download your own images from google, annotate them andperform transfer learning relatively fast. [Here](https://github.com/fastai/course-v3/blob/master/nbs/dl1/lesson2-download.ipynb)
So you find all geometrical shape that you want and update some bigge model, or train your own from scratch

Comment: there are other images with dotted rectangle and dotted arrow shapes too. How to approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the Pointnet architecture a shot : https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet (as an alternative to the already suggested pretrained CNN)

A simpler approach : you could try to hand engineer some features from your set of points and feed that into an MLP

Comment: sure i will give it a try